# How to access file browser path in Angular 6

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I am implementing a web project using MEAN stack and Angular 6. There I have a file type input to select files from browse icon. I want to get the selected file's browser path. I tried to find a proper method for it. But did not get. Can anyone help me with that.
This is my html input.

```
    <div class="input-group">
              <input type="file" class="form-control" #fileInput name="milespecMap" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"/>
    </div>
```

This is my .ts file.

```
 handleFileInput(file: FileList) {
    this.selectedFile = file.item(0);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      this.currentMapDetails.milespecUrl = event.target.result;
      console.log(reader.onload);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.selectedFile);
  }
```

Comment: what's browser path for a file? for example?

Comment: When I select choose file, a file explorer opens and I can select a file. I want to get that location path.

Comment: You can get file and fake path from the browser, not physical path to your file.

Comment: I want to use it to convert tiff to png (eg: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiff-to-png) . Is it ok to get the fake path?